# Bring an item to the top of the list

Tags: jquery, html

I must be able to manipulate a list with jquery. I created a list with an element already:

```
<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">

<li id = "1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <p id = "elem1"> Carne </p>
  <button id = "mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
  <button id = "canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
  <button id = "top" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">TOP</button>
</li>

</ul>
```

Now, I wish I could bring the item to the top of the list after clicking on the "top" button. I had thought of a function that saves the element that must be brought up, deletes it and rewrites it in the list at the top, but it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lista1").on('click', '#top', function() {

     $ogg = $(this).closest('li');
        $ogg.remove();

    $("#lista1").append($ogg);  

  });
});
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you add code snippet? Do you have more than one lis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lista1").on('click', '#top', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().prepend($(this).parent());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all change your Top button ids to class and then use `insertBefore` method to insert your clicked button `li` to top

JQuery:

```
$("#lista1").on('click', '.top', function () {

        $ogg = $(this).closest('li');
        $ogg.remove();

        $($ogg).insertBefore($("#lista1 li:eq(0)"));

    });
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">

    <li id="1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <p id="elem1"> Carne </p>
        <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
        <button id="canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
        <button  class="badge badge-primary badge-pill top">TOP</button>
    </li>
    <li id="1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <p id="elem1"> Carne </p>
        <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
        <button id="canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
        <button class="badge badge-primary badge-pill top">TOP</button>
    </li>
    <li id="1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <p id="elem1"> Carne Last</p>
        <button id="mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
        <button id="canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
        <button class="badge badge-primary badge-pill top">TOP</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

For insert `$ogg` to top of list you [should](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/#prepend-content-content) use `.prepend()`.
When you use `.append()` `$ogg` add to end of list.

I'd like to give you advice about using ID, Be careful with id in html, in my example of code I use classes for binding events. Otherwise you can get the strange behavior of your script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lista1").on('click', '.top', function() {

    $ogg = $(this).closest('li');
    $ogg.remove();

    $("#lista1").prepend($ogg);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">

  <li id="1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id="elem1"> Carne </p>
    <button class="badge badge-primary badge-pill mod" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
    <button class="badge badge-primary badge-pill canc">X</button>
    <button class="badge badge-primary badge-pill top">TOP</button>
  </li>

  <li id="2" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id="elem2"> Carne 2</p>
    <button class="badge badge-primary badge-pill mod" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
    <button class="badge badge-primary badge-pill canc">X</button>
    <button class="badge badge-primary badge-pill top">TOP</button>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insertBefore()` to place the `li` before the first `li` in the list.

There is no need to remove the `li`.

```js
$("#lista1").on('click', '#top', function() {
    var li = $(this).closest('li'); // parent of the button
    li.insertBefore('#lista1 > li:first-child');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">

  <li id = "1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id = "elem1"> Carne </p>
    <button id = "mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
    <button id = "canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
    <button id = "top" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">TOP</button>
  </li>
  
  <li id = "1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p id = "elem1"> Lorem ipsum </p>
    <button id = "mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
    <button id = "canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
    <button id = "top" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">TOP</button>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `prepend` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lista1").on('click', '#top', function() {
     $ogg = $(this).closest('li');
        $ogg.remove();
    $("#lista1").prepend($ogg);  

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lista1" class="list-group">

<li id = "1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <p id = "elem1"> Carne </p>
  <button id = "mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
  <button id = "canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
  <button id = "top" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">TOP</button>
</li>
<li id = "2" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <p id = "elem2"> Carne 2</p>
  <button id = "mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
  <button id = "canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
  <button id = "top" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">TOP</button>
</li>

<li id = "3" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <p id = "elem3"> Carne 3</p>
  <button id = "mod" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modifica</button>
  <button id = "canc" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</button>
  <button id = "top" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">TOP</button>
</li>


</ul>
```